# Set the Iframe width and height to 100% as per page size Not working

Tags: html, asp.net, css, iframe

I have tried following code. But it is not showing the iframe in proper way. Height and width of Iframe is very small. Iframe should take the height and width as per page size.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #left {
            float: left;            
        }

        #right {
            float: left;           
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div >
            <div id="left">
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="b1" OnClick="b1_Click" Text="Click" />
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <iframe id="ifr1" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to have 100% height on your html and body tags too or have a set height on one of the parent tags of the iframe

Comment: I set the height and width on body and div tags to 100%. Still it is not showing in the proper way.

Comment: how big do you want the iframe - if you give specific dimensions to your `#right` then your iframe will take up that width and height.

Comment: I don't want to give the specific width and height to iframe. Height and width should apply according to page size so I have given the 100% height and width to the iframe.

Comment: in which case you don't need to float your left or right: http://jsfiddle.net/jFVsr/4/.  The only thing i would say is that as you have left, your 100% height for the iframe will overflow the viewport

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/jFVsr/

```
html, body {height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: red;}
```

EDIT: Now the iframe fills the whole screen.

```
#left {float: left; width: 100%;}
#right {float: left; width: 100%;}
#form1 {background-color: beige; overflow:hidden; height: 100%;}
#ifr1 {border:none; height: 100%;}
```

Comment: I tried above code. Iframe is taking the height of full page it only worked in chrome but in IE and firefox height is small and another query, why iframe is not taking the remaining space of page as width.

Comment: Have another look. I think this is what you need isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are floating the element #right and not giving it any width or height it will take the width and height of its content. But the content has relative dimensions as well, so this will collapse.

Relative height and width always refers to relative to the parent element, so give the parent a concrete height and width.

Comment: I set the height and width on body and div tags to 100%. Still it is not showing in the proper way. I don't want to give height and width in px